# Delete all misspelled words in Microsoft Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, spelling

I have numerous word documents with misspelt words that I'm hoping to batch delete. I've tried both of the solutions mentioned below, but they all seem to fail for me.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-remove-all-misspelled-words-in-ms-word-at/608dbb5d-e719-4b5f-b44e-1b0542b66bd7

```
Sub DeleteSpellingErrors()
Dim rng As word.Range, i As Integer
If Selection.Range.Start = Selection.Range.End Then
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
Else
    Set rng = Selection.Range
End If
If rng.SpellingErrors.Count > 0 Then
    For i = rng.SpellingErrors.Count To 1 Step -1
        rng.SpellingErrors(i).Delete
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/remove-all-misspelled-words-in-my-word-document/b686c318-c1fc-4d90-9e56-e922bb556abd

Using these macro codes causes my microsoft word to freeze (I'm using a 10th gen intel i7) indefinitely. Despite having waited for hours, there still hasn't been any progress. It seems to me like these codes only work for shorter documents, but because my word docs have more than 200 pages, it seems to freeze.  Does anyone have any other code suggestions?  Better yet, does anyone have any suggestions that allow me to batch delete misspelt words across multiple word docs?  Currently, I am deleting misspelt words one document at a time.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-remove-all-misspelled-words-from/99d0e766-d7eb-445e-a7c6-c5503714952d?messageId=aceea053-d759-478c-ad89-92f2be30538e. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this code snippet is a bit faster:

```
    Sub DeleteSpellingErrors()
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim cur As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
    Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
    For i = 1 To cnt
        cur.Select
        cur.Delete
        Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
        Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub
```

Most probably you will have to re-run the procedure two or three times as I see that SpellingErrors.Count is not exact.

This re-run can be avoided with this other coding:

```
Sub DeleteSpellingErrors()
    Dim cnt, i As Long
    Dim cur, Last As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
    Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
    Set Last = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToLast)
    i = 1
    Do While cur <> Last
        cur.Select
        cur.Delete
        Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
        Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
        DoEvents
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

For testing purposes the document consisted of 107 pages with more than 3000 spelling errors and it took few minutes (about 3 or 4) of execution.

This is another version, that needs just one run to delete all the spelling errors, for Graham Mayor's add-in:

```
Function DeleteSpellingErrors(doc As Document) As Boolean
    Dim cnt, i As Long
    Dim cur, Last As Range
    If doc Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
    End If
    Do
        cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
        If cnt <= 0 Then Exit Do
        Set Last = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToLast)
        Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
        For i = 1 To cnt
            cur.Select
            cur.Delete
            'Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
            Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
            DoEvents
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Loop
    DeleteSpellingErrors = True
End Function
```

Comment: When you delete items from a collection it is necessary to iterate through the collection in reverse, as the OP has done, otherwise you will only delete half the items in the collection.

Comment: Sorry, but in this last code I have shown all the spelling errors were deleted and I verified it.

Comment: I don’t doubt that your code will get the job done, eventually, but it will be slower than what the OP already has.

Comment: Sorry again, but with the OP the code could last hours to do the job, while, as I said, with the last code I presented it took few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful code! After trying various different codes, I found your first code to be the only that worked! It didn't cause my word doc to freeze up. I just needed to re-run it two or three times and it pretty much delete all the misspelled words.  But now, I'm trying to batch apply the macros to numerous word doc files in a single folder. I downloaded Graham Mayor's add-in (http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm) but its batch "user defined process" (macro) requires a function name. I tried modifying ur code to a fn name but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Or do you have any other macro code suggestions that can do batch macro processing?    Fyi, I modified your code to get it to work with the Graham Mayor add-in by replacing  "Sub DeleteSpellingErrors2()" with   "Function DeleteSpellingErrors2(ByRef oDoc As Word.Document) As Boolean" .  The rest is kept the same.

Comment: @XavierJunqué Hi Xavier, regarding my last question on batch processing, I've posted it onto a new post, with reference to the code you gave me. If you have any thoughts or keen to see other ppl's answers, plz check out the post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970881/how-to-execute-a-macros-across-multiple-word-documents

Comment: Please, take a look at the last snippet I have added for Graham Mayor's add-in. It needs just one run to delete all the spelling errors. Kind if you give me some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine on my PC with a document that has 350 spelling errors.

If you have a 200+ page document it would be better to disable screen updating whilst your macro runs.  I would also add a 'doevents' statement to the for loop so that at least the CTRL Break will halt the program.  Initially you may also want to debug.print the count of errors to see how the macro is progressing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteSpellingErrors()

    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    If Selection.Range.Start = Selection.Range.End Then
    
        Set rng = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
        
    Else
    
        Set rng = Selection.Range
        
    End If
    
    If rng.SpellingErrors.Count > 0 Then
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Debug.Print "Total errors = ", rng.SpellingErrors.Count ' for debugging only
        
        For i = rng.SpellingErrors.Count To 1 Step -1
    
            DoEvents
            rng.SpellingErrors.Item(i).Delete
        
            Debug.Print i, rng.SpellingErrors.Count ' for debug only.  Note Count doesn't change
            
        Next
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.ScreenRefresh
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```