# How to execute a macros across multiple Word documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a macro code (courtesy of Xavier Junqué, see code snippet 1 below) which allows me to [delete all misspelled words in a Microsoft Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70950960/delete-all-misspelled-words-in-microsoft-word-document?noredirect=1#comment125449928_70950960). I'm hoping to execute this code across all word docs in a single folder. There are hundreds of word documents. Can anyone tell me how? I've tried to use Graham Mayor's (GM) [batch process add-in](http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm), which I saw some ppl recommend on other forums, but the add-in seems to require a "function" line in the code (eg. Function MyUserDefinedProcess(oDoc As Document) As Boolean). I tried adding this function line into my code, replacing the sub line (see code snippet 2), but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any other macro solutions for batch execution of macros or can advise me on what I'm doing wrong with the GM add-in?  Many thanks!

```
#Code Snippet 1: the code I'm trying to execute across multiple files...
    Sub DeleteSpellingErrors()
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim cur As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
    Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
    For i = 1 To cnt
        cur.Select
        cur.Delete
        Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
        Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub

#Code Snippet 2: Same as above code but with function line instead of sub...
    Function DeleteSpellingErrors(ByRef oDoc As Word.Document) As Boolean
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim cur As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
    Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
    For i = 1 To cnt
        cur.Select
        cur.Delete
        Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
        Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
        DoEvents
    Next
End Function
```

---

5 Feb
@Xavier: Based on your advice, here's what I did...

1. I cut "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" out of the "...STARTUP" folder and paste it into "...Word" folder.
2. I open a new blank word doc > developer> macro> type in abc and click "create macro"
3. The visual basic editor appears. I can see the "abc" window but I can't see the DeleteSpellingErrors() macro.  I can see that this "abc" macro is under module 2, and there is already a module 1. If I open module 1, I'll find the delete spelling error macro code as per below (I previously already updated my code to match your suggested code, which is why it's already under module 1)

> ```
>  Function DeleteSpellingErrors(doc As Document) As Boolean
>      Dim cnt, i As Long
>      Dim cur, Last As Range
>      If doc Is Nothing Then
>          Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
>      End If
>      Do
>          cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
>          If cnt <= 0 Then Exit Do
>          Set Last = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToLast)
>          Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
>          For i = 1 To cnt
>              cur.Select
>              cur.Delete
>              'Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
>              Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
>              DoEvents
>              i = i + 1
>          Next
>      Loop
>      DeleteSpellingErrors = True
>  End Function
> ```

4. I replace the both module 1 and 2's contents with the code as per above. I save both macros and close the VBA editor, close the word document, and paste the "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" back into the startup folder.
5. I open the "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" file> batch process tab > "process folder" > user defined process, and type in "DeleteSpellingErrors". See screenshot below.
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI5w4.png)
6. Again, it instantly processes the batch macro and says its complete without actually doing anything to the underlying files.  I have two docm files in this folder for testing purposes. I've tried docx files to no effect as well.

---

@Xavier Please see below for the error message images I mentioned in my comments, and thank you as always. [Error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98GtI.png)   [Error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzpEc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me in a 107 page document and more than 3000 spelling errors. It took 3 minutes of processing and did the work in just one call from Graham Mayor's add-in.

```
Function DeleteSpellingErrors(doc As Document) As Boolean
    Dim cnt, i As Long
    Dim cur, Last As Range
    Do
        cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
        If cnt <= 0 Then Exit Do
        Set Last = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToLast)
        Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
        For i = 1 To cnt
            cur.Select
            cur.Delete
            'Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
            Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
            DoEvents
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Loop
    DeleteSpellingErrors = True
End Function
```

[image]

So, it is possible to execute the batch macro.

' **********************************************

Most probably there is not the last update of macro DeleteSpellingErrors(). In order to update properly, do the following:

1. Go to the folder that contains "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm", this is, folder:

C:\Users\ ... \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP

2. Move "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" to the upper folder:

C:\Users\ ... \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word

3. Open a blank Word document
4. Create a macro named, for example, "abc"
5. Now you should see macro "abc" and also macro DeleteSpellingErrors()
6. Replace both macros by the following

   ```
    Function DeleteSpellingErrors(doc As Document) As Boolean
        Dim cnt, i As Long
        Dim cur, Last As Range
        If doc Is Nothing Then
            Set doc = Application.ThisDocument
        End If
        Do
            cnt = doc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
            If cnt <= 0 Then Exit Do
            Set Last = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToLast)
            Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
            For i = 1 To cnt
                cur.Select
                cur.Delete
                'Debug.Print cnt & " " & i
                Set cur = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSpellingError, Which:=wdGoToNext)
                DoEvents
                i = i + 1
            Next
        Loop
        DeleteSpellingErrors = True
    End Function
   ```
7. Save the macro DeleteSpellingErrors()
8. Close VB window.
9. Close Word
10. Move "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" back to it's original folder.
11. Open "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm"
12. Do a batch processing: now it should work as expected.

I am not sure what is happening. Any way I have made a small VB.NET application to run Macros to Word Documents inside a folder. I have tried to debug as much as possible, but it would be nice to hear your opinion. You may download it at my site download page [here](https://xrjunque.nom.es/swdownload.aspx#wordmacros)

// **************************************** //

I have made a new release. Now you may enter your macros and save them with the application in a Word doc1.dotm file inside the START folder. The reason you can't see the macro DeleteSpellingErrors is becaus GM saves the macros in a protected .dotm file. The new release expects you not to save protecting and therefore you will have access to all your macros in doc1.dotm. It may be any name with the same extension v.gr. myMacros.dotm

The applicatin has a Help menu where you may follow the usage instructions.

Comment: Hi Xavier, thank you again for your advice. I tried your code and although it seems to work for the processing of single files, it doesn't seem to work for batch processing all documents within a folder. If I click "process folder", insert my folder address, choose "user defined process", enter "DeleteSpellingErrors", and click begin processing, it'll instantly say that the process has been completed without actually making any changes to any of the documents. I've created two folders to test, one with only docm files, and another with only docx files, but neither works. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hello Johnny. Thanks for your feedback! I have added some points in order to try to overcome the problem with the batch processing. I look forward for your comments.

Comment: Hi Xavier, thank you again for your help! It still doesn't seem to work, although I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I've updated my question to show the steps of what I did, plz scroll down the above question until you see "@Xavier"

Comment: Hi Johnny. Please, read my last paragraph and thanks again for giving me feedback.

Comment: In case everthing goes right, I will post the code if needed.

Comment: Hi Xavier, I just tried your application and it worked like a charm! I chose delete errors, selected my folder and it began to delete all misspelled words in each document one after another. The whole process was very smooth, and after it deleted everything, it generated a report and closed down all the word docs. Thank you so much Xavier, your app saved me so much time!

Comment: Regarding the GM add-in, I tried it on a different computer and this time, I received an error msg saying "unable to execute the process you defined. Ensure the procedure named DeleteSpelling Errors exists in the Normal template and try again." I'm not sure why this is the case (maybe because the other docm files in the folder don't have this macro saved?). But because your app already solved my problem, I'm in no need of further investigating this.

Comment: I have no substantive feedback for your app because it worked so well! My only suggestion would be to blur out the "macro" name bar if the user selects "delete spelling errors" because it's not needed. Also if the user selects "Execute word macro", I believe that the user must insert the name of a macro that they've already saved in Word's VBA editor? It would be nice to have a sentence that makes it clear that the macro need to have aleady been saved in word (or add a text box for the user to insert their macro code and batch execute it directly without having to first save it in VBA editor).

Comment: That's all I can think of, it is a great app. Thank you again Xavier, my problem is now resolved!

Comment: Hi Xavier, after using your app a bit more, I've noticed that it can't seem to batch process more than 5 files at a time without being stopped by various error prompts. I've attached images of a couple of these error prompts at the bottom of my edited question above. I tried it on a different computer and encountered similar error msgs as well as a new error msg that says I do not have sufficient memory. These error msgs appear on approximately every fourth/fifth file that it processes. I have to rerun the app each time to continue processing the remaining files.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would also encounter this problem on your end? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I will look into this problem as soon as possible, thanks.

Comment: Thank you Xavier, for some reason, I couldn't upload the error message images before. I've just re-uploaded it now, you should be able to find it at the very end of my question above.

Comment: @Johnny: I have taken into account as much as possible all your suggestions, but I look forward for your comments. Please, look at the appended comments in my post. Thank you. (You will have to download the new version from my site (above).

Comment: Hi Xavier, thank you for all your effort updating your app so quickly. I just used the delete spelling errors option and it worked smoothly batch processing 20+ files! I think the current app is really great! For the "execute word macro" option, I selected and followed your instructions in creating a blank document, clicking on macros and selecting the saved blank doc. But I'm not sure what comes next. Your help instruction suggests adding in the macro code, but I'm not sure if I'm to add the code into the blank doc (>create macros) and save, or insert the code into the app itself.

Comment: In the app, I only see the Macros text line which I believe is where the macros name goes into, as it can't accommodate the code. Was there meant to be a text box in the app for me to insert the code? If not, I presume that the code needs to be saved into the blank word doc. I'll try this tomorrow once my comp finishes batch processing the delete spelling errors, I look forward to updating you on this.

Comment: There is a help menu option. But if you click on "Macro" button, a openFileDialog will ask you which word with macros file to open. Then a dialog box will appear and where you may add your macros.

Comment: I have replace Application.ActiveDocument by Application.ThisDocument because ActiveDocument is the document shown on top of the screen, while ThisDocument is the document related to the macro in execution. Calling the macro from the applicaion it is irrelevant done that it does not execute the mented instruction.

Comment: Hi Xavier, for some reason, the dialogue box where I insert the macro code wasn't showing up. I re-downloaded and re-installed the app and now it is showing up properly. However, after I insert the folder address, type in the code name "DeleteSpellingErrors", and clicked start, one of the word docs in the folder that needs to be processed opens up briefly and then closes. At this point, the app says it is processing with progress at 0%, but it won't make any actual progress. I've waited for many hours with no progress. It doesn't seem like the app is processing anything.

Comment: However, the app doesn't seem to be frozen, because the buttons on the app still respond visually when I hover my mouse over them. The computer appears to be idle with no pending processes. I tried with a different computer but also encountered the same problem.

Comment: Have you first clicked on button Macros and added the macro to a .dotm or .docm file?

Comment: Please, take a look to the Help menu option.

Comment: I have updated the site with a new version of the application. I hope it works better.

Comment: Hi Xavier, I saved the blank file as .dotm file and named it "Macro.dotm". The folder I am testing it with contains both docm and docx files. I have just re-downloaded and reinstalled the plugin but unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work. I would enter the macros code in the popup box > accept > enter "DeleteSpellingErrors" into Macro, choose the folder address, and click start. It would open up the first word doc from the folder that I am processing and then close it instantly. Then a notepad file would open saying 1 files processed.

Comment: The "Delete Spelling Errors" option still works, its just the "Execute Word Macro" option that's not working. I'm not sure why, I just tried it on both computers and had the same problem mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Hello Johnny. Please, leave a comment in my site with the code of the macro that is not working, so I can debug it my computer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Xavier, let me test it abit more and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Xavier, I just left a comment on your site, looking forward to your thoughts, thank you!

Comment: Hi Johnny. Thanks for your comments. I have made major changes to the application's code. The new version is on my site. Hope this time it works! Thanks before hand.

Comment: Thank you Xavier, I will examine the app tomorrow and let you know how I go

Comment: Hi Xavier, I have reinstalled the app but it unfortunately still doesn't work. When I run the app, the status at the bottom changes to "please, wait" and the app looks like its processing something, but it doesn't make any progress, and there are no word files that open/close, which usually indicates that the macro is working. However, the app is not frozen, and if I hover my mouse over "cancel“, the button would flash. If I click cancel, the button would grey out and nothing else happens (the app does not revert to initial state)

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I have released version 1.0.0.14 on my site. As the application is opening Word should open also. Do not close Word. Let me know, please, if you see any activity in Word's window, after click on "Start".

Comment: Also, it could be necessary to move GM .dotm document to other folder than START.

Comment: Thank you Xavier, I reinstalled the new version but it unfortunately still doesn't work. I would encounter the same problem I encountered before. Do you mean to move the "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" file to another folder other than startup?

Comment: Yes, try moving first "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm" to another folder other than startup. Then, run the application and, please, tell me if after the click on "Start" button if you see Word's window and any activity in it?

Comment: Alternatively, instead of moving "BatchProcessDocuments Ver 4.7.dotm", you may rename DeleteSpellingErrors macro name to, lets say, DeleteSpellingErrorsB and run the macro with this new name.

Comment: Prior to what I lastly said, it would be convinient to save the macro directly into the doc1.dotm file and then run the application.

Comment: The macro had an error I was not aware: ThisDocument does not exist in Word. I have modified the macro here -please modifiy it on your macro file- and there is version 1.0.1.2 at my site.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code (add exceptions ect.):

```
Private Sub DelErrorsInFiles()
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim fileName As String
    
    Const folder As String = "C:\Test\" '"\" at the end is important
    
    fileName = Dir(folder)
    Do While fileName <> ""
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=folder & fileName)
        DeleteSpellingErrors oDoc
        oDoc.Save
        oDoc.Close
        DoEvents
        Set oDoc = Nothing
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Function DeleteSpellingErrors(ByRef oDoc As Word.Document) As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Debug.Print oDoc.Name
    Debug.Print oDoc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
    Dim i As Long
    Do While oDoc.Range.SpellingErrors.Count > 0
        oDoc.Range.SpellingErrors(1).Select
        Debug.Print CStr(i) & " " & Selection.Text
        Selection.Delete
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then
            oDoc.UndoClear
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenRefresh
End Function
```

Comment: Hi deku, thank you for your advice! I've tried adding your code as a module and then running Graham Mayor's batch process > "process folder" > user defined process, and type in "DeleteSpellingErrors". But it also processes it instantly, saying its complete without actually making any changes to the underlying files. I'm not sure why its not working for me. I'm using Word 2019. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't mention about Graham Mayor's batch process (because I didn't use it).
You have to run DelErrorsInFiles only. You have to change Const folder to your path. Thats all.